# Issue with Initializing JPanel Components in IntelliJ's GUI Designer

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ's GUI Designer to create a form with the following component hierarchy:

- JPanel (name: "loginPanel")

  - JPanel (with additional components)
  - JPanel (with additional components)

As per my understanding, the GUI Designer should automatically generate initialization code for these components in the associated .java file. However, when I run the application, the loginPanel (the topmost JPanel in the hierarchy) appears to be null. I have attempted to manually initialize the component, only to receive the following warning: "Assignment to UI-bound field will overwrite field generated by UI-Designer."

I'm relatively new to Swing, and I've been searching online for a solution to no avail. Could someone help me understand what might be going wrong in my approach, and how I can correctly initialize the JPanel components without encountering the warning?

```
public class loginForm extends JDialog {
    private JTextField txtEmail;
    private JPasswordField txtPassword;
    private JButton btnSubmit;
    private JPanel loginPanel;
    private JButton btnExit;
    
    **... code up until this point was generated automatically ...**

    private loginFormDatabaseHandlers dbHandler = new loginFormDatabaseHandlers();

    public loginForm(JFrame parent) {
        super(parent);
        setTitle("Login");
        setContentPane(loginPanel); **... the line of code that throws a NullPointerException ...**
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(450, 474));
        setModal(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        **... more code ...**
    }
}
```

I've tried to manually initialize the JPanel, "loginPanel", but this just simply overwrites whatever it is the UI-Designer's generated.

I've also tried to "custom create" the component, simply to initialize it within the method that gets created within the .java file, but this just overwrites the design properties I've set for it using the UI-designer within the .form file.

Comment: I've answered it here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/16450144676882-Issue-with-Initializing-JPanel-Components-in-IntelliJ-s-GUI-Designer